# comparing data in two tables taking time

Tags: performance, compare, hbase, difference, database-scan

I need to query table1 find all orders and created date (  key is order number an date)).

In table 2 ( key is order number an date) Check if the order exists for a a date.

For this i am scanning table 1 and for each record checking if it exists in table 2.  Any better way to do this

Comment: Could you please show me your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this situation in which your key is identical for both tables, it makes sense to have a single table in which you store both data for Table 1 and Table 2. In that way you can do a single scan  on your data and know straight away if the data exists for both criteria.

Even more so, if you want to use this data in MapReduce, you would simply scan that single table. If you only want to get the relevant rows, you could define a filter on the Scan. For example, in the case where you will not be populating rows at all in Table 2, you would simply use a [ColumnPrefixFilter](https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/ColumnPrefixFilter.html)

If, however, you do need to keep this data separately in 2 tables, you could pre-split the tables with the same region boundaries for both tables - this will be helpful when you do the query that you are aiming for - load all rows in Table 1 when row exists in Table 2. Essentially this would be a map-side join. You could define multiple inputs in your MapReduce job, and since the region borders are the same, the splits will be such that each mapper will have corresponding rows from both tables. You would probably need to implement your own MultipleInput format for that (the [MultiTableInputFormat](http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/mapreduce/MultiTableInputFormat.html) class recently introduced in 0.96 does not seem to do that map side join)